# Which is the most appropriate way to model an action on a object in a REST API?

Tags: rest, oop, semantic-web

I'm developing an API to interact with a Semantic Web knowledge base. Now I need to model some actions on objects in the knowledge base which perform several stuffs, for example create links to other objects, create objects and change fields of the object.

In object oriented programming one would have ane object method (for example obj.accept() which do all these stuffs).

How is the appropriate way to model such an action in REST?

Answer (score 0):

> How is the appropriate way to model such an action in REST?

You define a document that describes the action, and you use the standardized [transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) semantics to deliver the document where it needs to be.  The server, upon receiving the document, does something useful.

On the web, the most common way to do this is with forms.  You define a list of keys, possibly with default values, and create an HTML form.  The web browser renders the form to its client; when the form is submitted, data is collected from the input fields, and the browser creates an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` document by applying standardized processing rules.  The browser then builds an http request, using this document as the body and various pieces of meta data.  That message is then sent to the server for processing.

An alternative to forms is to use remote authoring semantics: the "browser" gets a copy of a document from the server, allows the client to make edits to the local copy, then builds the appropriate http request to request that the server modify its own copy of the document as the client did.

In other words, the REST interface is a facade that your code wears to that it can pretend to be just another web server on the internet.